# How can I change a button's color back?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I am using python tkinter to make my gui and I want the user to be able to use a key on their keyboard to similate a button press. With this, I need to make it look like they hit the button by changing its color. I have this so far:

```
def clickedButton(event, number, button):
    global outputCalc

    outputCalc.config(text = number)
    button.configure(bg = "red")

numbers1Button = Button(root, text="1", padx=90, pady=90, bg='#FFFFFF', activebackground='#D9D9D9')
numbers1Button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: clickedButton(event, 1, numbers1Button))
root.bind('<Key-1>', lambda event: clickedButton(event, 1, numbers1Button))
```

When I make it sleep and then change the background color back to white it doesn't do anything. I have also tried some other methods, but none of them have been successful. However, when I use this code, It successfully changes the button's color to red. Is there any way I can make this work? Also, if there is an easier way of doing it I would like to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that tkinter `mainloop` can only update widgets when it takes back the control, i.e. after `clickedButton()` returns.  So if you change the button to red, sleep and change it back to white inside the function, then you will only see the button in white after the function.

You can use `.after()` instead of `sleep()` to change the button to white after some delay:

```py
def clickedButton(event, number, button):
    ...
    button.configure(bg="red")
    button.after(100, lambda: button.configure(bg="white"))
```

However I would suggest to bind `<KeyRelease-1>` to same function and determine the color based on the bind event type:

```py
def clickedButton(event, number, button):
    ...
    color = "red" if event.type == EventType.KeyPress else "white"
    button.configure(bg = color)

...
root.bind('<Key-1>', lambda event: clickedButton(event, 1, numbers1Button))
root.bind('<KeyRelease-1>', lambda event: clickedButton(event, 1, numbers1Button))
```

Comment: Thanks it works, this isn't related but since it seems like you have experience, do you know why this isn't working?

string = outputCalc.cget("text")
outputCalc.config(text = string)

Comment: @DPGGintec You are updating the text with the current one, so you don't see any change.